# TLS with username/password with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, ssl

Is it possible to send username/password to a `TLS` server in `NodeJS`?
I would like to create a custom `VPN`-sort of server with `NodeJS`.

I've tried other `TLS` `VPN` services where I can login to a `TLS` session with username/password - but I don't know if it's default `TLS`?

I know how to  use `client` `certificate` authentication, but that is not what I want, as I want to be able to authenticate users via username/password from my `database`, so I dynamicaly can add/edit users etc.

Not sure if its `PEAP` or `EAP` I'm thinking of or...

Comment: [Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Totally agree, also read them - no mentioning of username/password.

Comment: *"I want to be able to authenticate users via username/password from my database"* - I was never suspecting you'd find an answer in the docs, merely suggesting it's a place to start to build your custom authentication.

Comment: I'm aiming for a none custom solution, so I ex. can use MotionPro SSL VPN client and other TLS/SSL VPN clients for setting up the TLS session.

Answer (score 0):

TLS by itself has no concept authentication with username and password. If you need this you need to implement this on top of TLS, for example with HTTP over TLS (i.e. HTTPS).

Comment: How does regular SSL/TLS VPN clients with username/password authenticate?
I'm looking for TLS sessions indepedent of protocol on top.

Comment: @AlfredBalle: SSL VPN have a protocol on top on of SSL/TLS. The SSL part is used for encryption only but does not care about user based authentication or encapsulating of network packets.